# Word to describe someone who takes their experience as absolute truths

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

For example, say that this individual personally knows 5 doctors and and all of them are very bad in character. Therefore this person assumes that all doctors must be like that.

This person has had a very bad experience with one niche of people and he/she blames or thinks like that of all other people from that niche.

Moreover, they are hellbent on their experience and they take it as absolute truth.

Is there a word to describe such a person?

Comment: Isn't that what humans (and animals) do – make judgements based on their life experience? They become **biased**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**narrow-minded** [[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrow-minded): not willing to accept opinions, beliefs, behaviors, etc. that are unusual or different from one's own